# how to change text in a div with a link, and keep changing it every time link is clicked

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

is there a way to change the text inside a div using a link, but to keep changing it every time the link is clicked? I tried innerhtml and I can get it to change once, but after it is changed how to change yet again to new text. The end result is every time the "next" link is clicked new text loads? I do not have any code to start from so any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure you want the text to be, but you should be able to customize this to make it work no matter where you're getting the text from:

```
(function(){
    var texts = [
    'This is the first message',
    'This is the second message',
    'This is the last message'
    ], i = 0;

    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = texts[0];

    document.getElementById('left').onclick = function(){
        if(i <= 0)
            i += 3;
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = texts[--i%texts.length];
    }

    document.getElementById('right').onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = texts[++i%texts.length];
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YDA7v/

Comment: thanks this helps a lot... ok so I forgot to mention, I have next and back arrows so with this i can go forward and change text but how to go back?

Comment: @Aaron White I edited my post to have a left and right event handler, and added some simple buttons to my jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/YDA7v/1/